# Toggle view dynamically on click ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have mapped list of data from JSON. When I clicked on of the item it should open a crawl with additional details from the same JSON file. I am able to map everything one I clicked bit I was not able to toggle. How do I do toggling.

> This is my render method

```
 render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>API</h1>
      <div>
        {this.state.apis.map(api => (
          <div
            key={api.id}
            id={api.id}
            onClick={this.handleCrawl}>
            {api.title}


          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
      {this.state.apis.map(api => (
        <div
          key={api.id}
          id={api.id}>
          {this.state.showCrawl[api.id] && (

            <SwaggerUI url={api.opening_crawl}/>
          )}

        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> This is the method for toggling. When I clicked an item the SwaggerUI component shows up and If I clicked the same link it hides.
>
> The problem is if I clicked the 2nd link 1st link still shows. I need other view to be closed.

```
handleCrawl = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;
  this.setState(current => ({
    showCrawl: { ...current.showCrawl, [id]: !current.showCrawl[id] }
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just don't spread the previous state's props.

try this:

```
handleCrawl = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;
  this.setState(current => ({
    showCrawl: { [id]: !current.showCrawl[id] }
  }));
};
```

Because in your code:

initial state:

```
{showCrawl: {}}
```

Say first time you click the first one(id: 1), your state become:

```
{showCrawl: {1: true}}
```

then u click the second one(id: 2)

```
{showCrawl: {1: true, 2: true}}
```

That's not your expected. Right?

So just don't spread the property, it should be going well.

Comment: My pleasure~~~.

Comment: How can I add a style when this clicked link is active in react.

Comment: U can give it a className.
Like This:
      {this.state.apis.map(api => (
        <div
          key={api.id}
          id={api.id}>
          {this.state.showCrawl[api.id] && (

            <SwaggerUI className={this.state.showCrawl[api.id]?"active":""} url={api.opening_crawl}/>
          )}

        </div>
      ))}

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can show or hide an element in a react component like this:

```
{this.state.showComponent ? (<Component/>) : (null)}
```

as an alternative, you can control the hiding/showing of the element in the component itself, with a `show` prop:

```
<Component show={this.state.showComponent} />
```

-- edit

I think I misunderstood your problem. Your problem is that you only want `SwaggerUI` to show for one thing at a time, but it's showing for multiple.

This is because of the way you designed your function,

```
handleCrawl = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;
  this.setState(current => ({
    showCrawl: { ...current.showCrawl, [id]: !current.showCrawl[id] }
  }));
};
```

You're only ever ADDING ids to showCrawl, not changing the ids that you toggled previously. You'll have to fix that function

Comment: Or shorter `{this.state.showComponent && <Component />}`.